# Does google analytics screen view event give information about time spent on a page?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am using google analytics inside my react native project. I have imported them from `import analytics from "@react-native-firebase/analytics";` and every time I load a screen I am logging this event. For instance:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const logAnalytics = async () => {
        await analytics().logScreenView({
          screen_name: "Profile Screen",
          profile_id: id,
        });
    }
    logAnalytics();
  }, [])
```

And I do see the event being logged inside google analytics. However I am not sure, if this gives me info about how much time does the user spent on the given page? I am logging the event inside use effect, that is when the page is being rendered initially. Do I need to call the event again after the user leaves the page?

I need to track how much time does the user spent on given products, thats why I started using the event  `logScreenView` as everyone suggested, but I am not sure if it gives me that info? Do I need to use it alongside with another event for instance when the user leaves the page?